# Поломалось видео: "libavcodev may be vulnerable…"

Tags: ubuntu, firefox

Внезапно перестало работать видео.
Мелькает первый кадр, а потом черный экран и сообщение

> libavcodev may be vulnerable or is not supported, and should be updated for play video

Ubuntu 14.04, Firefox 50.0

```
dpkg -l | grep libavcodec
ii  libavcodec-extra                                      6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1                             all          Libav codec library (additional codecs meta-package)  
ii  libavcodec-extra-54:amd64                             6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1                             amd64        Libav codec library (additional codecs)
rc  libavcodec53:amd64                                    4:0.8.16-0ubuntu0.12.04.1                           amd64        Libav codec library
rc  libavcodec54:amd64                                    6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1                             amd64        Libav codec library
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я нашла обходной путь.
Надеюсь, здесь кто-нибудь предложит решение получше.

Очевидно, проблема появилась недавно и связана с обновлением Firefox.
Поиск в Гугле привел меня в [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1137029/libavcodec-may-be-vulnerable-message-in-firefox).
Принятый ответ предлагает

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:heyarje/libav-11
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libav-tools
```

а затем

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Я так и сделала, а потом еще

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Но это не помогло :(

Тогда я сказала Firefox-у использовать старый libavcodev,
как предлагал другой ответ на тот же вопрос.

- Пишем `about:config` в адресной строке,
- соглашаемся взять на себя ответственность,
- и меняем `media.libavcodec.allow-obsolete` на `true`.

Теперь Firefox показывает видео, но он стал менее безопасным.

Upd: В версии Firefox 51.0.1 вернула все обратно. Вроде все работает.

Answer (score 0):

libavcodec может быть уязвим или не поддерживается --- выдаёт ошибку, видео мелькает после чёрный экран ?

Помогло следующее

> Пишем в поиске  about:config в адресной строке,
>       соглашаемся взять на себя ответственность,
>       и меняем media.libavcodec.allow-obsolete на true.

Теперь Firefox показывает видео, но он стал менее безопасным.

после  я в терминале прописал

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:heyarje/libav-11
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libav-tools
```

ну а пjтом вернул всё обратно `media.libavcodec.allow-obsolete` с этого true на false

и видео вcё равно работает